# Referencing new columns inside transform

Tags: r, variables, transform

I have a dataframe with columns labeled A,B & C. I want to add new columns that are calculated from the existing columns AND the new columns themselves. To achieve this I tried using the transform function like this:

```
Data = transform(Data,
          NewD = A + B,
          NewE = C * NewD
)
```

But this gives an error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'NewD' not found

I also tried the cbind function like this:

```
NewD = Data$A + Data$B,
NewE = Data$C * New$D
Data=cbind(Data,NewD,NewE)
```

But it gets cumbersome when the number of additional columns(functions) grows.

How can I reference NewD inside the transform function, or is there a better way to apply multiple functions like this. I want Data to contain columns A, B, C, NewD & NewE without having to call the transform funciton numerous times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hadley has a `mutate` function in his `plyr` package that does precisely this. Here is the same example used by @Karsten using `mutate`. I find `mutate` code more readable for such tasks, as it does not require any temporary assignments inside.

```
require(plyr)
d = data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
mutate(d, c = a + b, d = b * c, e = c * d)
```

Comment: I'm trying a few of the answers above but this looks great. Is there a similar aternative to the 'Summarise' function? That is, it doesn't add to the existing dataframe. I couldn't see one in the library.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe something like this

```
d <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=6:10)
transform(d, c=tmp <- a+b, e=b*tmp)
```

does it?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of ways.  We illustrate using the built in data frame `BOD`:

**within**

```
> within(BOD, { a <- Time + 1; b <- a + 1 })
  Time demand b a
1    1    8.3 3 2
2    2   10.3 4 3
3    3   19.0 5 4
4    4   16.0 6 5
5    5   15.6 7 6
6    7   19.8 9 8
```

**my.transform**

`my.transform` is defined [here](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e2/help/07/09/24707.html) and allows one to reference new columns:

```
> my.transform(BOD, a = Time + 1, b = a + 1)
  Time demand a b
1    1    8.3 2 3
2    2   10.3 3 4
3    3   19.0 4 5
4    4   16.0 5 6
5    5   15.6 6 7
6    7   19.8 8 9
```